# How to solve "Http failure response for (unknown url): 599 undefined" using Ionic?

Tags: angular, typescript, http, ionic-framework

I am getting this error while working on an Android emulator(Android device), no errors showing while I work on Chrome.
This is my file AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="0.0.1" package="io.ionic.starter" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|uiMode" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" android:exported="false" android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" />
        <activity android:label="Share" android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.encode.EncodeActivity" />
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />
</manifest>
```

This is in file config.xml:

```
<platform name="android">
        <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="22" />
        <icon density="ldpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="mdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="hdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <splash density="land-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
    </platform>
```

Using this in providers in my app.module.ts:

```
{provide: HttpBackend, 
      useClass: NativeHttpFallback, 
      deps: [Platform, NativeHttpBackend, HttpXhrBackend]
    },
```

This is the error I am having: [image]

The method giving error is a GET method using http: HttpClient.
Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

"599 (Informal convention) network connect timeout error This status code is not specified in any RFCs, but is used by some HTTP proxies to signal a network connect timeout behind the proxy to a client in front of the proxy."

1 Android studio uses its proxy server for virtual devices by default. Lets go ahead and check if that's our culprit. Open the settings menu for the virtual device you're using. Then under the "Settings" submenu, go to the 'Proxy' tab and uncheck 'Use Android Studio HTTP proxy settings'. Change this to 'no proxy', save your projects and reboot.

[IMG Android Virtual Device Proxy Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7NLoZ.png)

2 Look over your module pages and check they are setup properly.

3 Check if there's an easy way to packet dump virtual devices in android studio. Else you can try running a small proxy server to record network traffic and filter that to find your answer. You would set this in the same menu we saw in part 1.